# Why won't my javascript code work in a HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio

Hi I am new to coding and trying to learn webb developpment. I were following and looking at a tutorial  making a hamburger menu but cant get the javascript to work. Am I doing somthing wrong or have a forgot to download somthing in Visual studio code beacause i  can't find  any erors in the code.

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmSdm.png)

[CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6hlx.png)
[CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDJ6K.png)

Comment: Your code should be posted **here**.

Comment: As Pointy mentioned, don't post images of code, just post the code here directly. As far as your issue goes, first thing I notice is that you've spelled `document` as `dokument` in your javascript

Answer (score 2):

Your spelling `document` wrong

```js
var More = dokument.getElementById('More');
...
```

Javascript is annoying and will silently fail when an error happens. To view the errors hit f12 in your browser and go to the `Console` tab, they should show up in a big red banner :)